# Jquery-nice-select plugin not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, select

I am using Jquery-nice-select plugin.(http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/).

I have two select dropdowns. In the first one, I am displaying the country name form database and In second dropdown I am displaying the state name depending upon the country name.

I am able to display the both but the issue is, When I am selecting the country name then state name is displaying but that are not displaying inside select drop down. even I am not able to select it. Please check the below image.
Would you help me out in this?

Before

[image]

After selecting the country name

[image]

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');
$country_list="SELECT id,name FROM countries";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($country_list)) {
    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $country_name);
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--country name-->
     <select  name="country_data" class="myselect form-control country_data">
                        <option  value="" disabled selected>Select your country</option>
                            <?php  
                             while ($stmt->fetch()) {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $country_name;?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                     </select>

    <!--state name-->
                <select  name="state"  class="myselect form-control state_get">
                <option value=''>Select state</option>
                </select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nice-select.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').niceSelect();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".country_data").on('change',function(){
var country_id=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
    url:"process.php?key=state_retrive",
    method:"POST",
    data:'id='+country_id,
    success:function(data){
     $('.state_get').html(data);
     //alert(data);
    }
   });
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
include('connection.php');

switch($_GET['key']) {
case 'state_retrive':state_retrive($conn);break;
default : redirect('index.php');
}

function state_retrive($conn)
{

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

  $country_id=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
  $state_data="SELECT name,id FROM `states` WHERE country_id=?";
  //echo $state_data;
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($state_data)) {
/* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $country_id);
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($state_name, $id);
    /* fetch value */
    echo $states="<option value=''>Select state</option>";
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      $states="<option value=".$id.">".$state_name."</option>";
      echo $states;
      }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
 $conn->close();
}
}
 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a link or a demo we could access?

Comment: @OfirBaruch, Where should I add it? Because data is coming from the database. I have only above code.

Comment: Amm... use your browser's inspect tool (developers console -> elements tab) and add the output of the dropdowns after selecting a country to your question.

Comment: <option value=''>Select state</option><option value=164>Eastern</option><option value=165>Manu'a</option><option value=166>Swains Island</option><option value=167>Western</option>

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I got this output in the network tab->response

Comment: Good, but I need to see the "Elements" tab - the source code of the dropdowns (unlike "view source", it would be updated as results of the response)

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I am using Mozilla, I haven't got developers console -> elements tab

Comment: Which tabs do you have? maybe it has a different name in mozilla.

Comment: right clicked->inspect Elements-> than I have Inspector, Console, Debugger, Style editor, performance, Memory, Network, Storage.

Comment: Inspector -> you'll the actual source code of the page, copy only the parts of the dropdowns (or screenshot if you find it difficult).

Comment: Yes, I added Image of the source code

Comment: Try adding: "$('.state_get').niceSelect('update');" after "$('.state_get').html(data);" in the success callback.

Comment: I believe I've found the problem. One more thing - in the inspector, click on the "+" that's next to the "<div class="nice-select ...country-data" so we could see what's in it.

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plugin works this way:
It takes the select element and manipulate the DOM by hiding the select element and adding a styled DIV element that has a better UI but still behaves as a SELECT element.

The first time you call the plugin, it has its effect but after updating the state's element - you need to tell the plugin that there's new data.

So, first, we would like to update the SELECT element of the states.
Afterwards we want the tell the plugin that we've updated that select element so it would update the DIV.

```
success:function(data){
     $('select.state_get').html(data); //Make sure you update the SELECT element. not the DIV (by adding "select.xxx").
     $('select.state_get').niceSelect('update'); //Tell the plugin to recreate the DIV.
     //alert(data);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. Thank you very much, I am trying this issue more than 5 hours and you solved it within 5 min. Realy appreciate. Thank you. Upvote form my side.

Comment: Thank for sharing your idea

Answer (score 0):

Try to Check the Height of the State DropDown list when it open , check by inspecting it on Browser. Its Height is fixed try to change the Height. Check list height for State DropDown, May it is effected by another CSS files you using . Inspect it and fix.

Comment: I haven't added any CSS, I am using only plugin link.

Comment: Inspect the .list class in Browser for List Height

Comment: I am getting output link <option> state name </option>. I tried whatever I know, Is there any other help?

Comment: please add JS Fiddle , if still u facing the same problem .

Answer (score 0):

You can append data in jQuery for that you need to pass json array from process.php file.

```js
var myselect = $('<select>');
$.each(resultData, function(index, key) {
    myselect.append( $('<option></option>').val(key).html(key) );
});
$('.state_get').append(myselect.html());
```

Comment: it won't work directly, you need to create response in same format.