# How to rerun Script and update based on event

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am trying to get the following code to update a secondary dropdown menu based on a selection made in the first dropdown. I know the code works as I've tested it, but it isn't working  on my site and I've discovered the issue is being caused another plug-in I'm utilising.

The solution was described in another post however I lack the Javascipt knowledge to implement it in my script.

Post with Solution: [Jquery-nice-select plugin not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075145/jquery-nice-select-plugin-not-working-properly))

I believe the solution is stating that I first need to ensure the jquery is rerun after a change is made to the first dropdown menu, then I need to update the Select element (#carlist) and then finally div that holds the second dropdown menu (#topline).

My code is below and I would be very grateful if somebody could outline the code I need to add the this script to accomplish this.

```js
<script>
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = document.getElementById("car");
    var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 form-cols">
    <div class="make">
        <select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()"> 
            <option value="">-- Car --</option> 
            <option value="VO">Volvo</option> 
            <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option> 
            <option value="BMW">BMW</option> 
        </select> 
    </div>  
</div> 
<div class="col-lg-3 form-cols" onselect="Data()">
    <div id="output">
        <select id="carmodel"></select> 
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function re-write using JQuery. should work for you...
[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/xobopuvigi/edit?html,js,console,output) Make sure you have jquery library added.

```
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
  let car = $('#car').val();
  $('#carmodel option').remove();
  if(car !== ''){
    carsAndModels[car].forEach(modelType => {
      $('#carmodel').append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value",modelType)
       .text(modelType)); 
    });  
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not make sense... What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the data simply isn't appearing in the second dropdown list, as said in my original message I believe this is because the nice-select plugin must be recalled after the selection is made to the first Drop down, If I remove the nice-select plugin your query works fine, as did the one I had listed already, however with the plugin on the page, neither query populates the second dropdown list

Comment: Can you tell me a code that would rerun the Nice-select plugin once the first dropdown is selected?

Comment: I have not had a chance to test or setup your "Nice-select" plugin